# GridLayout stretched to fit screen evenly

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to have a grid of 5 ImageViews (with different size) aligned on a GridLayout, but I'm having trouble. Below is a glimpse of what I'm trying to accomplish (each number represents an ImageView with lines denoting how big I'd want them to be):

```
------------------------
|          |  2  |  3  |
|          |     |     |
|    1     |------------
|          |  4  |  5  |
|          |     |     |
------------------------
```

I previously accomplished this using nested LinearLayouts, but was warned of performance issues. Hence, I am trying GridLayout, to no avail. Also, I've seen solutions where people set fixed Space width, but that won't work for my case, as I want this to fit the device's screen horizontally for any screen size. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use one Activity with 5 fragments. Within the fragments you can put the imageviews.